# Foundation 6 menu not responsive

Tags: php, sass, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 6 (first time) and I have the following top horizontal menu.  It works and has the foundation class styles. I have not added any personal styles to the menu class, but when I get to a small screen or narrow my browser to a smaller width, the menu items are not wrapping downward - or stacking.  They disappear off the screen to the right, as though I were using a fixed width.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns menu-centered">
       <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
          <li><a href="customer-reviews.html">Customer Reviews</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've looked and many samples of code like this and am not sure what I am missing.  Help?  thanks.

Comment: Asked a question and self answer 2min after asking... Read documentations before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it in the foundation.zurb site:
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/responsive-navigation.html

"Responsive Menu"
"The Menu has some responsive CSS classes built in, which allow you to re-orient a menu on different screen sizes."

```
<ul class="vertical medium-horizontal menu">
```